# Open layer maps feature appears at the wrong place

Tags: javascript

#### Problem:

Im trying to add some coordinates to features from an array, but they appear in the wrong position. For some strange reason when I try to hardcode the coordinates the features appear in the correct positions. I checked via `console.log` what values I get from the array and they are correct!

#### Code:

```js
var places = [{
  description: "FIRST",
  icon: "images/staro.png",
  points: [{
    name: "A",
    typ: "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR",
    description: "test",
    position: "19.535807,50.064800"
  }, {
    name: "B",
    typ: "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR",
    description: "test",
    position: "21.2562269,50.9707909"
  }, {
    name: "C",
    typ: "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR",
    description: "test",
    position: "20.535807,50.064800"
  }, {
    name: "D",
    typ: "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR",
    description: "test",
    position: "21.053,50.8591"
  }, {
    name: "E",
    typ: "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR",
    description: "test",
    position: "21.2562269,50.3707909"
  }, {
    name: "F",
    typ: "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR",
    description: "test",
    position: "21.2562269,50.6707909"
  }, {
    name: "G",
    typ: "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR",
    description: "test",
    position: "20.2562269,50.7707909"
  }]
}];

var map;
var vectorSource;
var vectorLayer;
var rasterLayer;


var oldprojection;
function myFunction() {
  var point;
  for (var x = 0, xl = places.length; x < xl; x++) {
    var place = places[x];

    // sort all points by name
    place.points.sort(function(p1, p2) {
      return alphaSort(p1.name, p2.name);
    });

    for (var y = 0, yl = place.points.length; y < yl; y++) {
      var point = place.points[y];

      var latlng = point.position.split(",");
      //console.log(latlng[0]+" "+latlng[1])
      getFeature(latlng[0], latlng[1]);
    }
  }
  alert("boom");

  //getFeature(19.1316683,52.107985 );
  //getFeature(29.1316683,52.107985 );
  //getFeature(49.1316683,52.107985 );
  //getFeature(99.1316683,52.107985 );
  //getFeature(89.1316683,52.107985 );
  //getFeature(79.1316683,52.107985 );
}

alphaSort = function(a, b) {
  var chars = "AĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPQRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻaąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuvwxyzźż",
    pos = 0,
    min = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
  while (a.charAt(pos) === b.charAt(pos) && pos < min) {
    pos++;
  }
  return chars.indexOf(a.charAt(pos)) > chars.indexOf(b.charAt(pos)) ? 1 : -1;
};


function getFeature(lat, lng) {

  features = [];

  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    //geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lat ,lng], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    //
    //geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lat ,lng], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    //geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lat ,lng], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lat, lng], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),


    name: 'Null Island',
    LAT: lat,
    LNG: lng,
    population: 4000,
    rainfall: 500
  });

  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/examples/data/icon.png'
    }))
  });

  iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
  features.push(iconFeature);
  vectorSource.addFeatures(features);

  return features;
}

function registerClickListener() {

  var element = document.getElementById('popup');

  var popup = new ol.Overlay({
    element: element,
    positioning: 'bottom-center',
    stopEvent: false,
    offset: [0, -50],

    delay: {
      show: "1500",
      hide: "5"
    },

  });
  map.addOverlay(popup);

  // display popup on click
  map.on('click', function(evt) {
    $(element).popover('destroy');

    // delay to prevent the popup bug
    var delayMillis = 300; //1 second

    setTimeout(function() {
      var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature) {
          return feature;
        });
      if (feature) {

        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        popup.setPosition(coordinates);
        $(element).popover({
          'placement': 'top',
          'html': true,
          'content': feature.get('name') + " " + feature.get('LAT') + " " + feature.get('LNG')
        });
        $(element).popover('show');
      } else {
        $(element).popover('destroy');
      }
    }, delayMillis);
  });

  // change mouse cursor when over marker
  map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
    if (e.dragging) {
      $(element).popover('destroy');
      return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
    var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
    map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
  });

}

function initMap() {
  // view
  vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    //projection: 'EPSG:4326'
  });

  // source

  vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });

  // raster layer
  rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
  });

  // map
  map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
    //interactions : ol.interaction.defaults({doubleClickZoom :false}),
    renderer: 'canvas',
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([19.1316683, 52.1079857], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      //center:  [19.1316683 ,52.1079857],
      zoom: 6
    })
  });
  registerClickListener();
}




$(document).ready(initMap);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Icon Symbolizer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walkermatt/ol3-popup/master/src/ol3-popup.css" />




  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #map {
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>


  <script src="js/points.js"></script>
  <script src="js/js.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click to add features to the map</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="map" class="map">
    <div id="popup"></div>
  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. **See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**_

Comment: Basically the features should appear in Poland . I have tried to use ol.proj.transform([lat ,lng], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') to convert the coordinates without sucess . I read many tutorial saying the same thing and I really after 8 hours I have no clue whats going on . You can run the snippet to see that the features appear in the sea.

Comment: I had to parse the values from the array as float..stupid me 
   ` parseFloat(latlng[0]),parseFloat(latlng[1]) `

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. You can write that as the answer. And mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to parse the values from the array as float..stupid me

```
parseFloat(latlng[0]),parseFloat(latlng[1])
```